# Matlab's blockproc vs for loop Speed

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing

I need to perform computations for each pixels in an image. I currently have code with a double for-loop that takes a long time. Would converting this to "blockproc(I,[1 1],fun)" give any kind of speed up?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it easier to test it for yourself?

Comment: I second @EitanT's comment.  But if that's too much work for you, trust me -- I'm a consultant -- it won't help.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the Parallel Computing Toolbox and R2012a or later, you can [use `blockproc` with the 'parallel'-option](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/new-features-for-high-performance-image-processing-in-matlab.html). Alternatively, you can `parfor` the outer loop. While it's possible `blockproc` is still faster, you should definitely profile the two options side-by-side.

Alternatively, you may be able to achieve important speed gains by changing your algorithm - for example, break down a 2D filter into 2 1D filters, etc.

---

/aside: The big advantage `blockproc` can have over nested-loop solutions is that it can work on images that are too big to fit in RAM, i.e. it takes care of loading sub-images for you.

Comment: I guess that for a fair comparison `parfor` should be in the setup as well.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: You're right. I've updated my answer.